# I would like to know if Americas Army 3 can be played on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: installation, games, playonlinux

I know that this is not serious question but i would really like to know? Play on linux provides Steam account to install, but can u install AA3? 
Thx for your answers

Comment: Check the Wine site, www.winehq.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Sort of](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17275) but it's probably not worth it...

- The game itself mostly works. Moving, shooting, etc.
- There are problems with the HUD that means it doesn't show (fairly inconvenient) and like most games through Wine, there are some performance issues that may stop you playing on a low-end computer.
- Online play doesn't work unless you play on a non-PunkBuster server. This likely means you can only play with other people desperate enough to play through Wine and cheats who hack the game. Online play will probably not be plentiful and it probably won't be fun.